# Mathematica; turn solutions of Nsolve into a list

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am using mathematica's Nsolve to solve a polynomial. When solved, Nsolve traditionally gives solutions like this:

{{x -> 1}, {x -> 2}, {x -> 3},{x -> 4}}

However, I need to transform this output into a list of numbers, so it looks like:

{1, 2, 3, 4}

How can I do this? There must be a simple way.

Comment: simple rule replacement:  `x/.{{x -> 1}, {x -> 2}, {x -> 3},{x -> 4}}` gives `{1,2,3,4}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a list `{{x -> 1}, {x -> 2}, {x -> 3},{x -> 4}}` and you want to do the same thing to each item in that list, you want to replace the `{x -> n}` with `n`.

This is a very common thing to want to do in Mathematica. There is a function `Map` which accepts a function and a list and does that function to each item in the list. You can look up `Map` in the help pages and try to make sense of it.

Your list has `Rule`'s in it. So what you have is `{{Rule[x,1]}, {Rule[x,2]}, {Rule[x,3]},{Rule[x,4]}}`, which Mathematica abbreviates into `{x -> 1}`, etc. You can look up `Rule` in the help system and try to make sense of it.

Let's look at one way of doing what you want

```
sol = {{x -> 1}, {x -> 2}, {x -> 3}, {x -> 4}};
f[r_] := ReplaceAll[x, r];
Map[f, sol]
```

That defines a function `f` which uses the `ReplaceAll` function with `x` and an individual `Rule` to replace all the `x`'s in `x`, and there is only one, with the value from that rule. And then the `Map` does this over and over until it has processed all the items in your list. and the result is `{1, 2, 3, 4}` which is what you wanted.

Now the culture of Mathematica is that you try to abbreviate everything, you always try to use a handful of punctuation characters instead of using the name of a function. That can be pretty difficult for a new user to understand. Here is a different way a Mathematica user might write that instead.

```
x/.#&/@{{x -> 1}, {x -> 2}, {x -> 3}, {x -> 4}}
```

and that will give you the same result. You can look up `/.` and `#` and `&` and `/@` in the help system and try to make sense of those.

There are almost always a dozen different ways of accomplishing anything in Mathematica. at least several of which are almost completely incomprehensible. If you can, choose a way of doing things that you think you understand and can remember and use without making too many mistakes. But this routinely seems to become a contest to see who can accomplish something using a few less characters or who can make this run in a few less seconds.

Answer (score 0):

just right the following command

```
sol = {{x -> 1}, {x -> 2}, {x -> 3},{x -> 4}}
x /. sol
```

the result will appear as intended